# How to sort data in MongoDB by id

Tags: mongodb

I have a set of data that I added in my db by order. Later I opened my db and I see that the order has changed. The question is how to sort data by `id` to make it more readable?

[image]

Comment: why are you using two IDs ?

Comment: one is by default, you mean it can bring some issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at the end of the input FILTER field shown in your image there is OPTIONS `button` click on it and it will suggest the sort option, then you just have to chose the field you want to sort with.